# Xcode keeps trying to login into Apple developer account with account I deleted

Tags: ios, xcode

A year ago I worked on an Iconic/Cordova app and I helped build the iOS side of things. I have a MacBook Pro and an iPhone so I was setup to test the iPhone app, whereas another developer had a Windows machine and an Android phone, so they focused on testing that side of things.

We were working for an entrepreneur who had created an account in the Apple developer portal. Though he added my developer account to his "team" in the Apple developer portal, I was never able to make that work, so I simply started using his credentials:

cap55@cornell.edu

Now I am working for a different company. I am working on a React Native app.

Oddly, when I try to build the iOS part of this in Xcode, I get this error:

```
Code Signing Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'cap55@cornell.edu'. An unexpected failure occurred while logging in (Underlying error code 1100).
```

I tried several times to specify my personal account, but nothing seemed to work, so I opened up the Preferences of Xcode and I deleted the old 'cap55@cornell.edu' account.

Just to emphasize this: if I open Xcode, and then Preferences, and then Accounts, there is only one account, and that is my personal one. There is no record of 'cap55@cornell.edu' anywhere.

I restarted Xcode.

Then I tried to build again. And again I get:

```
Code Signing Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account 'cap55@cornell.edu'. An unexpected failure occurred while logging in (Underlying error code 1100).
```

It seems like Xcode is hiding this account somewhere that I can not delete? Where should I look. I want to eliminate this account.

Comment: The only important question, I think, is what your Team is set to for this target. Look under Signing -> Development Team in the Build Settings.

Comment: Though you might also want to look in your keychain and see what your developer credentials are...

Comment: Matt, I can manually set "Signing -> Development Team" to my account "Personal Team" but how do I connect this to the team account? When I log into developer.apple.com using the same credentials then I can see that I'm listed as part of the company team. But it feels like there is some disconnect between what developer.apple.com knows and what my Xcode knows.

Comment: Here's another idea. Open your _Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist_ and search for "cap55@cornell.edu". Is it in there?

Comment: @matt -- no. But I think I managed to shake the error by opening up the KeyChain app and deleting almost everything.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of my suggestions, as you may recall. Maybe your old development certificate was still sitting in there.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the KeyChain app and deleted almost everything in there. Then I restarted Xcode. The problem now seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your target's build settings to see what team the "Signging" section is set to.  Both in General and also in the "Build Settings" tab for the targert.

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: I've tried both "automatic" and also "personal team" which are the only two options.